# Loader size dependent on source

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm working on a little system of message dialog windows in QML. For this I'm using a container with a [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) to load the different messages (these are not just text but text and graphical symbols layouted hence loading a QML file for each individual message). By default these message windows have the same size, so I have my size information directly in the container. But some messages can be longer, therefore I'm looking for a way to use the `height` of my loaded component if it exceeds the default value.
The way I see it my problem can be split into three parts:

- How to have a container sized by the dimensions of its children?
- How to access the size information of the loaded component through my `Loader` object?
- How to selectively use the larger size?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access loaded object using `item keyword`. 
Example if your loader id is `idLoader`, then the created item is `idLoader.item`, you have 2 solutions  to do what you want:

1:How to access the size information of the loaded component through my loader object?

```
Loader{
id:idLoader
width: (item !== null && typeof(item)!== 'undefined')? item.width : 0
height: (item !== null && typeof(item)!== 'undefined')? item.height: 0
}
```

2: How to have a container sized by the dimensions of its children? & How to selectivly use the larger size?

```
  Loader{
        id:idLoader
        width: childrenRect.width
        height : childrenRect.height
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's would've been my attempt to do this, but I was mislead by the autocompletion suggestions, and for item there were none. I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, untested. Take the max of the child's preferred height or a hard-coded minimum, whichever is larger.

```
Loader {
   height: Math.max(item ? item.implicitHeight : 0, 200)
}
```

Comment: The `implicitHeight` attribute is very interesting, thank you!